# Pop-up message from command line

Tags: command-line, windows-8.1, cmd.exe

In Windows XP this command:

```
msg %USERNAME% Hello there!
```

results in a popup message being displayed. This doesn't work on Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 (not tried Windows 7) because `msg` is not available. Are there alternate simple options in later versions of Windows?

*UPDATE*

I copied `msg.exe` from a Windows XP installation (%WINDIR%\System32) to my Windows 8.1 installation...and it works! Is this fine, perhaps there's a more recent version I should use instead? Am still interested if there is another (simple) option.

Comment: `msg` does work in Windows 8 and 10...what do you mean by "not available"?

Comment: `msg.exe` was not in my path on Windows 8.1 (though most other normal DOS commands like `dir`, etc. were available). The example from the questions results in: `'msg' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` Not sure why it was missing on my installation, but a copied version from Windows XP seems to work.

Comment: Works for me in windows 10 server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying `msg.exe` as you did should work fine. <s>But it should be there by default. `msg` was not removed from Windows 7, 8, or 10. You can try running `sfc /scannow` and see if that restores it.</s>

**EDIT:** As @DavidPostill pointed out, `msg.exe` is apparently not included in Windows Home editions. Your workaround of copying `msg.exe` from Windows XP, or Pro version of Windows, is probably the best and only way to get it to work.

---

I don't know what your needs are, but alternatively you can create a `.vbs` file and use that to display a message box:

`msgbox ("Hello World!")`

Comment: Thanks @wysiwyg. After a bit of research it appears you're right and `msg.exe` should have been there...not sure why it wasn't. Haven't tried `sfc /scannow` yet because the XP version does the job. The `.vbs` approach was tempting, but getting it to work with a customised message (the `%1` part of a batch command) was proving tricky. Also the `/W /TIME` components of `msg.exe` are easy to use.

Comment: HTH. Yes, I assumed `msg` was preferable. Just added VBscript as an alternative, because you had asked for other options.